# jQuery/UI/Tab ajax not loading flash cfcharts in IE7/8

Tags: flash, jquery-ui, jquery, cfchart

I have a coldfusion page that uses JQuery UI TAB to load another coldfufion page which includes a cfchart in flash format. But this works completely fine in FF.(everything was loaded, flash cfchart, tables ...)

```
<li><a href="xxx.cfm?param=#xxx#">XXX</a></li>
```

However in IE: all of the html elements that are generated with the flash object are loaded, except the flash object and embed tags do not show up at all after running an ajax call in IE.

how can i fix this error to let the flash cfchart display inIE?

Any suggestions or insight would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just faced this same issue. The problem comes from some extra JavaScript ColdFusion injects to help IE deal with active content as a result of the Eolas patent lawsuit from a few years back. Modern versions of IE shouldn't need this script shim now that Microsoft settled with Eolas.

I wrote up a CF custom tag that strips out this extra junk

```
<cfswitch expression="#thistag.executionmode#">
<cfcase value="end">
    <!--- Strip out the opening NOSCRIPT tag and anything from the closing </NOSCRIPT> to the end of the content --->
    <cfset thistag.generatedcontent = REReplace(Replace(thistag.generatedcontent, "<NOSCRIPT>", ""), "</NOSCRIPT>.*$", "")>
</cfcase>
```

Just wrap your CFCHART calls with this tag:

```
<cf_chartscrubber>
    <cfchart>...</cfchart>
</cf_chartscrubber>
```

Seems to be working okay for me, but this is for an intranet application so I can afford to experiment a bit.

Answer (score 0):

try to init flash on init of page, and then communicate with it via ExternalInterface from AJAX side you have.